# Trying to understand the definition of Hilbert functions

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, hilbert-polynomial

Suppose $M$ is a finitely generated graded $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$-module where $k$ is a field. Then the Hilbert function is defined to be
$$H_M(s)=\dim_k M_s$$

It is said that $M_s$ must be finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space, or else the submodule $\bigoplus_s^\infty M_i$ would not be finitely generated.

I don't find this very obvious, although it seems to be a trivial fact as Eisenbud writes it like a comment. Is it because if $\bigoplus_s^\infty M_i$ is finitely generated by $m_1,\dots, m_r$ where $m_i\in M_{k(i)}$ for some $k(i)\geqslant s$, then we can say that each element $m\in M_s$ is linear combination of a subset $\{m_j\}$ over $k$ where the $m_j$ are in $M_s$ for degree reasons? But if this is correct, why do we need to consider the larger submodule $\bigoplus_s^\infty M_i$ instead of just $M_s$?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a finitely-generated graded $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$-module and let the minimal degree of $M$ be $s$. If $a_1,a_2 \dots$ is a $k$-basis of $M_s$, then $a_1,a_2,\dots$ are part of a minimal generating set of $M$. Indeed, no $a_i$ can be written as a $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$-linear combination of $\{a_j\}_{j \ne i}$ and elements of higher degree, for degree reasons.

We thus consider the submodule $\bigoplus^{\infty}_{s} M_i$ of $M$ in your context that we may argue from the minimal degree. If we don't do this, there may be elements in degree $s$ that can be produced as a linear combination involving also generators in smaller degree; they are not minimal generators of $M$ but are of $\bigoplus^{\infty}_{s} M_i$.

Comment: Am I correct to say that if $a_1, a_2, \dots$ is a $k$-basis of $M_s$, which exists regardless of the finiteness of $\dim_k M_s$, then as none of them can be written as a $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$-linear combination of others and the minimal degree of an element we can have in $M_s$ is $s$, these elements must be "$k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$-linearly independent" in $\bigoplus_s^\infty M_s$. Therefore if the basis is infinite, $\bigoplus_s^\infty M_s$ will not be finitely generated?

Comment: But wouldn't this also be an immediate result if we argue that $M_s$ is finitely generated $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$-module and apply the same argument?

Comment: @GoogleME The issue is that $M_s$ does not usually inherit a $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ module structure. E.g., $x_1 \cdot M_s \subseteq M_{s+1}$. It can only inherit one if $x_i \cdot M_s=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out this crucial idea! This really improves my understanding of graded modules!